Can I view a ResourceDictionary in XAML designer?
I'm taking over an application from some colleagues, who have left the firm.
While debugging, I saw that some windows-like thing was shown, so I used the "Live Visual Tree" to know what I was dealing with, and so I've stumbled upon a XAML file, starting with <ResourceDictionary ....
When trying to open this XAML file in the XAML designer, I got the message that this file cannot be edited in design view.
Does this mean that something is wrong with my file? In case yes, where can I look?
If not, can anybody confirm that ResourceDictionaries are never viewable in Visual Studio's XAML Design view?

There is nothing wrong with the file. The visual XAML designer in Visual Studio however does not support XAML files with ResourceDictionary as root element.
